# Pass function to AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im a bit stumpled with how you can pass a function (delegate) to a directive in AngularJS and use it in the link-function. Maybe I am totally off so any pointers on how you would do it is greatly appreciated.

I have the following controller

```
        myApp.controller("QuestionCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

           $scope.filter = function(query) {
            console.log("filter filter", query);
           };

           $scope.replace = function(query, key) {
            console.log('replace replace');
           };
        }
```

This is the markup

```
<a class="Add Button" href="#" onsearch="filter(query)" onreplace="replace(hello, world)" showpane="#AddQuestionPane"><span>Ny fråga</span></a>
```

As you can see I've got 2 attributes that points to functions on my scope that I would like to use in my directive.

```
myApp.directive("searchreplace", function() {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                onsearch: "&",
                onreplace: "&"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("dblclick", function() {
                    scope.editMode = !scope.editMode;

                    if (scope.editMode) {
                        var replaceBox = angular.element('<input type="text" class="Search" placeholder="Ersätt" />');
                        replaceBox.keyup(function() {
                            //How do I call onsearch? Yes it is the wrong method, just a test
                            scope.onsearch({ query: replaceBox.val() });
                        });
                        element.after(replaceBox);
                    } else {
                        element.siblings(".Search").remove();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

I cant for the life of me figure out how to call the method on the scope. I want to specify it in the markup. Is that possible?

Is there a better solution to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see I put the onsearch and onreplace methods on the wrong element, of course it dont work then. Stupid of me! After I moved the attributes to right element (the one with searchreplace on it) everything works.